# Relative positioning to the image with always on top

Tags: html, css, css-position

[image]

Hi Guys i have applied Relative positioning to the image as the above screen cap . but what i required is to take this image to front of that gray menu bar . what should i apply for menu's CSS class to do that ?

for relative position of the image i used the following code

```
position: relative;
top: -Xpx;
z-index: 99;
```

Comment: I need a live example to see what's wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
z-index:999;
```

or some other really high number to force it above all other elements.

Answer (score 0):

Relative position is given to an element when you want to anchor (contain) other positioned elements inside it. If you want that image to appear on top of everything else you need to position it absolute. This, of course, depends on what it is you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the html and the full css this is my best guess: You need to set the gray bar to a `position:whatever` and then set the z-index on that one as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are applying the css style before the styling of the gray bar.
So you should apply the css styles on the image after the gray bar style or code.